# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy in ISO format in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am getting date in this format `01/01/2022` `(dd/mm/yyyy)`. And i have to convert it into `ISO` `format("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00")`. I've tried but I get invalid time value error.

```
const newDate ='01/01/2022' 
"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00"
```

Comment: What format is `01/01/2022`? US, or UK?

Comment: any  it should come like "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00

Comment: ...OK, what would `01/02/2022` be, then? Because in US format this is the second of January - ISO representation is `2011-01-02` , in UK format, this is the first of February - ISO representation is `2022-02-01`.

Comment: I think @VLAZ meant, is it day/month/year or month/day/year

Comment: yy-mm-dd like "1988-09-21T00:00:00.000+01:00"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var str = "25/09/2019";
darr = str.split("/");    // ["25", "09", "2019"]
var ISOFormat = new Date(parseInt(darr[2]),parseInt(darr[1])-1,parseInt(darr[0]));

console.log(ISOFormat.toISOString());
```

also refer this [link by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: Thanks let me try this one

Comment: thanks let me try this . :)